# What are "Generic Exceptions"?

Tags: java, exception, generics

Can anyone explain what is meant by "generic exception" and what "generic" means within the Java language context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Catching an exception that's high up in some exception class hierarchy - for example directly catching `Exception`:

```
catch(Exception e) { ... }
```

You should typically catch as specific an exception as possible, for example `IOException` and not `Exception` if `IOException` might be thrown.

Comment: Why? Sorry to seem facetious, but I get into this argument with my own devs all the time. E.g: "If I can put an explicit message in the generic, why should I bother maintaining a library of custom exceptions?". To which, my only recourse seems to be "because it's canonical". But if the app doesn't rely on specificity in the exceptions (custom data fields or whatever), it's really hard to come up with anything other than an appeal to authority.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding different catch blocks for the individual exceptions to the try block, a busy programmer may simply wrap the method calls in a try/catch block that catches generic Exceptions Like this

```
try{
}
catch(Exception e)
{}
```

This methodology is called Generic Exception Handling

In that case, the `catch` block sometimes catches exceptions that it was never intended to catch.

For Example it may sometime catch a `NullPointerException` is a subclass of `RuntimeException`, which, in turn, is a subclass of `Exception`, even though you never intended that you code may end up catching that exception.

So the generic `catch(Exception e)` catches all **subclasses of RuntimeException**, including `NullPointerException`, `IndexOutOfBoundsException` etc.Typically, a programmer does not intend to catch those exceptions

Comment: Sometimes referred to as `Pokémon Exception Handling` from the TV's catchphrase: *Gotta catch em all.*

Answer (score 0):

In that context, the word "generic" is being used in the normal English sense: i.e. "not specific".

It refers to exception class that is near the top of the exception class hierarchy.

Note that an exception class cannot be a generic class ... in the Java sense of generic types.  The JLS says:

> *"Note that a subclass of Throwable cannot be generic (§8.1.2).*" - [JLS §11.1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1)